# mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: apt, dpkg, 20.04, mysql

I am trying to install mysql-server by using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` but apt says this:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

after doing configure on dpkg it says

```
# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` and check for any errors and what it recommends.

Comment: update is succesful but installation have same error

Comment: Have you added ppas and other sources?

Comment: no, everything is still same as before

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? If yes, open a terminal and run `sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d/`, then `sudo nano mysql.cnf` and paste `[mysql]` and save. Again run `sudo nano mysqldump.cnf` and paste [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SrDjQFYvz8/). Save and retry `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If you still get errors ping me using `@kulfy` in comments otherwise I may miss your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Kulfy The paste that you linked to does not exist.

Comment: @Orphans Uh.. Oh!! Let me check if I can have contents of that file again. Also, please note that you need to create `mysql.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` (I missed `cd`ing in the comment). Can you please try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` only without creating `mysqldump.conf` (i.e., only with `mysql.cnf`) since I had no way to confirm that really worked?

Comment: @Kulfy Yeah I did try that, and it worked without the mysqldump.conf actually :)
Thanks! You are a lifesaver

Comment: @Orphans Excellent!!! I'll post an answer for future visitors. (I can see a deleted answer posted by a new user who was also not able to find the paste **:-(**)

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal window and create the directory mentioned in the error message using [`mkdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) with `p` option.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

`p` option will create parent directories as well, in case they don't exist.

Create a new file `mysql.cnf` in the above said directory and add `[mysql]`. That can be done using `tee` as well.

```
echo "[mysql]" | sudo tee /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

Finally try re-configuring packages using

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

---

<sup>***Note:** A special thanks to [Orphans](https://askubuntu.com/users/529875) for confirming the applicability of the answer in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2257333).*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, mysql server was not started,
so run the server with one of below command as

Five ways to start:

```
1. Start MySQL Server
2. sudo service mysql start.
3. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start.
4. sudo systemctl start mysqld.
5. mysqld.
```

and then try to connect with mysql client as

```
mysql -u username -p
```

then it is working fine.

Comment: MySQL was not started, as the output clearly say: `ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)`  Why do you think any of your proposal would solve the problem?